# OpenGL: Debug assertion failed

Tags: c++, opengl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL+(i))
GLuint shaderProgramID;
GLuint vao = 0;
GLuint vbo;
GLuint positionID, colorID;

#pragma region SHADER_FUNCTIONS
static char* readFile(const char* fileName)
{
//Open the file
FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
//Move the file pointer to the end of the file and determining the length
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long file_length = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
char* contents = new char[file_length + 1];

//zero out memory
for (int i = 0; i < file_length + 1; i++)
{
    contents[i] = 0;
}

//Here's the actual read
fread(contents, 1, file_length, fp);
contents[file_length + 1] = '\0';
fclose(fp);
return contents;
}

bool compiledStatus(GLint shaderID){
GLint compiled = 0;
glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
if (compiled) {
    return true;
}
else {
    GLint logLength;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    char* msgBuffer = new char[logLength];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, logLength, NULL, msgBuffer);
    printf("%s\n", msgBuffer);
    delete (msgBuffer);
    return false;
}
}

//Takes in source code as string
GLuint makeVertexShader(const char* shaderSource)
{
//Call GL to make a vertex shader and get the ID
GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

//Bind the provided source code to the shader ID
glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)&shaderSource, NULL);

//Compile the vertex Shader
glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);

bool compiledCorrect = compiledStatus(vertexShaderID);
if (compiledCorrect)
{
    return vertexShaderID;
}
return -1;

return vertexShaderID;
}

GLuint makeFragmentShader(const char* shaderSource)
{
//Call GL to make a fragment shader and get the ID
GLuint fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
//Bind the provided source code to the shader ID
glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, (const GLchar**)&shaderSource, NULL);
//Compile the fragment Shader
glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

bool compiledCorrect = compiledStatus(fragmentShaderID);
if (compiledCorrect)
{
    return fragmentShaderID;
}
return -1;

return fragmentShaderID;
}

#pragma endregion SHADER_FUNCTIONS 

void changeViewport(int w, int h)
{
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

//This is the function we are using each time the window needs to be redrawn
void render()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glutSwapBuffers();
}

GLuint makeShaderProgram(GLuint vertextShaderID, GLuint fragmentShaderID)
{
GLuint shaderID = glCreateProgram();
//Attach the vertex shader to the shader program
glAttachShader(shaderID, vertextShaderID);

//Attatch the fragment shader to the shader program
glAttachShader(shaderID, fragmentShaderID);

//Link all the shaders together
glLinkProgram(shaderID);
return shaderID;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//Standards
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
glutCreateWindow("Test");
glutReshapeFunc(changeViewport);
glutDisplayFunc(render);
glewInit();

//Verticies
GLfloat vertices_0[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, //0 -> Bottom Left
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, //2 -> Bottom Right
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };//3 -> Top Right
//Colors
GLfloat colors_0[] = { 1.0f, 0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f,//0
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,//1
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };//3

//Indicies -> Triangle 1 -> 0 1 2, Traingle 2 -> 1 3 2
//GLuint indicies_0[] = { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2 };


//Read the vertex shader
char* vertexShaderSourceCode = readFile("vertexShader.vsh");

//Read the fragment shader
char* fragmentShaderSourceCode = readFile("fragmentShader.fsh");

//Make Vertex Shader
GLuint vertexShaderID = makeVertexShader(vertexShaderSourceCode);

//Make Fragment Shader
GLuint fragmentShaderID = makeFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSourceCode);

//Make Shader Program
shaderProgramID = makeShaderProgram(vertexShaderID, fragmentShaderID);


printf("Vertex Shader ID is %d\n", vertexShaderID);
printf("Fragment Shader ID is %d\n", fragmentShaderID);
printf("Shader Program ID is %d\n", shaderProgramID);
printf("s_vPosition's ID is %d\n", positionID);

//Create vertex array object
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

//Bind Vertex array object
glBindVertexArray(vao);

//Create vertex buffer object
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

//Bind vertex buffer object
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

//Create Buffer ->7 Values for 4 vertices
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 7 * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL,         GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Starting at the beggining of the buffer, place the position data (3 values     for 4 verticies)
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 3 * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices_0);

//Starting after the placement of position data, place the color data (4 values for 4 verticies)
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), 3 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), colors_0);

//Generate the index buffer
//glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);

//Bind the buffer
//glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);

//Place index buffer data for the 6 indicies
//glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(GLuint), indicies_0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Get the position attribute from the shader
positionID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "s_vPosition");

//Get the color attribute from the shader
colorID = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "s_vColor");

//Tell the variables where they can find its info in the buffer
glVertexAttribPointer(positionID, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glVertexAttribPointer(colorID, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(3 * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

//Tell the program to use the shader program
glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
//Turn on the position variable in the shader
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionID);
//Turn on the color variable in the shader
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorID);

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

when I run the program it always show's below:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnChh.jpg)

and 
[window shows that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AjI5.jpg)

Could anyone please help me to solve it??# What's wrong with my code? I have already add "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" onto the Preprocessor Definition.

Comment: BDL is right. Double check those filenames, make sure they are in the same location as the executable. If they are not, ensure you qualify the filepath that your program needs to follow to reach them.

Comment: You passed NULL to fseek. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The breakpoint and the assertion already tell you most of it: It is not allowed to call fseek with a filepointer pointing to null since this indicates an invalid file.

I would guess that the path is wrong and thus the file cannot be opened. You should definitely add error handling and check whether `fopen` succeeds before issuing any file-access calls.

I'm not sure why you think that `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` could be related to the problem, since this definition supresses some warnings during compilation but does not change anything at runtime.